# How to sum up values in a nested array

Tags: ruby

I have an array in the following format:

```
arr = [
 ["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 13],
 ["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 13],
 ["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 10],
 ["OMRA001S16116037 1001", 10],
 ["OMRA001S16116037 0110", 9],
 ["OMAA002S16001014 0119", 9],
 ["OMAA002S16001002 0134", 9]
]
```

The first entries are the same code but with different numbers. What's the best way to make the entries unique and sum up the values on the right? The result should be like this:

```
[
 ["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 36],
 ["OMRA001S16116037 1001", 10],
 ["OMRA001S16116037 0110", 9],
 ["OMAA002S16001014 0119", 9],
 ["OMAA002S16001002 0134", 9]
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k, v), h| h[k] += v }
#=> {"OMAA002S16001006 1088"=>36,
#    "OMRA001S16116037 1001"=>10,
#    "OMRA001S16116037 0110"=>9,
#    "OMAA002S16001014 0119"=>9,
#    "OMAA002S16001002 0134"=>9}
```

You can call `to_a` to convert it back to an array.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).reduce(:+)] }
#=> [["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 36],
#    ["OMRA001S16116037 1001", 10],
#    ["OMRA001S16116037 0110", 9],
#    ["OMAA002S16001014 0119", 9],
#    ["OMAA002S16001002 0134", 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
arr.map.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k, v), o| o[k] += v}.to_a
#=> [["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 36],
#    ["OMRA001S16116037 1001", 10],
#    ["OMRA001S16116037 0110", 9],
#    ["OMAA002S16001014 0119", 9],
#    ["OMAA002S16001002 0134", 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |(s,v), h| h.update(s=>v) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.to_a
  #=> [["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 36],
  #    ["OMRA001S16116037 1001", 10],
  #    ["OMRA001S16116037 0110", 9],
  #    ["OMAA002S16001014 0119", 9],
  #    ["OMAA002S16001002 0134", 9]]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o+n }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for what `o` and `n` represent.

Note that

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |(s,v), h| h.update(s=>v) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"OMAA002S16001006 1088"=>36,
  #    "OMRA001S16116037 1001"=>10,
  #    "OMRA001S16116037 0110"=>9,
  #    "OMAA002S16001014 0119"=>9,
  #    "OMAA002S16001002 0134"=>9}
```

`.to_a` then converts this hash to the desired array of arrays.

I am not advocating this approach. My preference is for @Stefan's use of a counting hash.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reduce` and `to_a`:

```
arr.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |h, (k,v)| h[k] += v; h }.to_a
#=> [["OMAA002S16001006 1088", 36],
#    ["OMRA001S16116037 1001", 10],
#    ["OMRA001S16116037 0110", 9],
#    ["OMAA002S16001014 0119", 9],
#    ["OMAA002S16001002 0134", 9]]
```